# Files structure with styled component and CRUD

Tags: reactjs, redux

I do want to have a file structure by feature. But I'm using **Styled Component** and I have a lot of files.
For exemple in my `project` directory, which is an entity in my application, I have:

`Projects.js` `ProjectList.js` `ProjectCreate.js` `ProjectShow.js` `Card.js` `CardHeader.js` `CardBody.js` `CardFooter.js` `TasksCounter.js` `ProjectDescription.js` `CardAdd.js` `ProjectDelete.js` `actions.js` `reducer.js` `saga.js` `constants.js`

I could have more files but my pages are still under construction so I could add some more later. Should I split those files again? To have for example sub directories like `Projects` `ProjectCreate` `ProjectShow` put the common files in the root `project` directory and specific files into those three?

```
project
|_Projects
     |_index.js
     |_ProjectList.js
     |_Card.js
     |_CardHeader.js
     |_CardBody.js
     |_CardFooter.js
     |_TasksCounter.js
     |_ProjectDescription.js
     |_CardAdd.js
     |_actions.js
     |_reducer.js
     |_saga.js
|_ProjectCreate
     |_index.js
     |_Form.js
     |_actions.js
     |_reducer.js
     |_saga.js
|_ProjectShow
     |_index.js
     |_ProjectHeader.js
     |_ProjectContent.js
     |_actions.js
     |_reducer.js
     |_saga.js
```

I saw a lot of different approaches in more than a dozen of tutorials but the examples are always really simple with just a couple of features.

Better solution maybe, using **Ducks** and put every **Styled Components** in the same file?

Answer (score 1):

I usually make a separate folder called `views` for every react (custom) component.

```
views
 - Cards
   - index.js
   - module.js
   - test.js
   - styles.js
 - Button
 - InputFields
 - ...
 - ...
```

Inside each view, notice that there is an `index.js` that has the react component. The `module.js` will contain reducers and actions if any. `test.js` will have tests regarding that component only and finally `styles.js` or `styles.css/scss` will have styles

Comment: I suppose that means you have many many folders for just one feature?

Comment: Yes can be! But what is important is making sure that you make your components so that you can re use them in multiple places. And the components are self sufficient by their own as well